# Javascript cookie for plain text = Safe?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a datepicker navigation in which I save the clicked date as a string (2015-08-31) and save it in a cookie as such:

```
$datepicker_field.on('change', function (e) {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    //Create readable date from mm/dd/yyyy
    var splitDate = $(this).val().split('/');
    var readableDate = splitDate[2] + '-' + splitDate[0] + '-' + splitDate[1];
    document.cookie = "agendadate=" + readableDate;
  }
});
```

I do this so I can set the datepicker to that date on a pagerefresh. Making it easier for the user to navigate further.

Now my question is: Is this safe for XSS/Session Hijacking etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's no problem.
the value is from client and you save it on client side(cookie).
if client want to change it then it's up to them.
so i think it's okay.

cause security is needed to assure they can do what they can,
and they can't do what they can't.

Comment: Well, that was my case aswell. They can change the date by changing the datepicker. All the power to them! :-p Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any risk in exposing a date to a hacker. It would be risky if that information was the credit card number, or the users credentials that would allow them to automatically operate in your site.

But as your data is not sensitive information it's totally ok to store it in a cookie.